# How to fix: Undefined binding(s) detected when compiling SELECT query

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, knex.js, bookshelf.js

I trying to get all featurekeys with related features who relates to products with specific category, but receive error described below. What I do wrong?

My table structure:

```
Product:
id -> int
category_id -> int (one-to-many)

FeatureProducts: (many-to-many)
id -> int
product_id -> int
feature_id -> int

Feature:
id -> int
value -> string
featurekey_id -> int (one-to-many)

FeatureKeys:
id -> int
type -> string
name -> string
text -> string
```

```
Product.query((qb) => {
      qb.where('category_id', '=', params.category);
    })
      .belongsToMany(Featurekey)
      .through(Feature)
      .fetch({
        withRelated: filters.populate || populate,
      });
```

```sh
Error: Undefined binding(s) detected when compiling SELECT query: select `featurekey`.*, `feature`.`id` as `_pivot_id`, `feature`.`product_id` as `_pivot_product_id`, `feature`.`featurekey_id` as `_pivot_featurekey_id` from `featurekey` inner join `feature` on `feature`.`featurekey_id` = `featurekey`.`id` where `feature`.`product_id` = ?
```

Answer (score 0):

try to change your code

```
Product.query((qb) => {
      qb.where('category_id', req.params.category);
    })
      .belongsToMany(Featurekey)
      .through(Feature)
      .fetch({
        withRelated: filters.populate || populate,
      });
```

instead of this :

```
 Product.query((qb) => {
          qb.where('category_id', '=', params.category);
        })
          .belongsToMany(Featurekey)
          .through(Feature)
          .fetch({
            withRelated: filters.populate || populate,
          });
```